# Como criar um cookies para publicidades popup abrirem 1 vez só 24 horas

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, popup

Estou precisando de uma ajuda com o meu site. 
A um bom tempo uso o formato popup para modernizar meu site, porem ganho pela primeira vez que é exibido para o mesmo usuário no período de 24 horas...Só que esse popup está sendo aberto 4,5 e te 6 vez para o mesmo usuário. Gostaria de saber se tem como criar um cookies em javascript para essa publicidade abrir uma unica vez a cada 24 horas.

Para quem quiser dar uma olhada o meu site é esse aqui: www.filmestorrentslife.com

Comment: Popup de publicidade? É por isso q o uso de Adblock ssó aumenta. Telvez colocando de forma não invasiva em um lugar estratégico do site traga mais resultados

Comment: Sem dúvida o popkit.site é a melhor alternativa. Por 3 motivos: Sem marca no rodapé do Popup, Grátis e Customizável. E para sua necessidade: Sim, o sistema tem funções para escolher o tempo e quantidade de exibições por usuários. É só adicionar 3 linhas de código na <Head> do seu site. Espero tera ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar essas funções para te ajudar na criação, leitura e exclusão dos cookies

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

No seu caso basta utilizar mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
var x = readCookie('visualizou_popup')
if (x) {
    // achou o cookie não mostra pop up
} else {
    // mostra popup e cria cookie
    createCookie('visualizou_popup', 'true', 1);
}
```

Comment: Primeiramente muito obrigado pela resposta, mas sou leigo em javascript ... teria como vc editar e posta o código pronto para mim?